# I am trying to get response from the Openweather API but I am getting a 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
// MODULE
var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

// Directives
weatherApp.service('cityService', function() {
   this.city = "New York, NY";
});
```

// controllers

```
weatherApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope','cityService', function($scope, cityService){
      $scope.city = cityService.city;

      $scope.$watch('city', function(){
        cityService.city = $scope.city;
      });
}]);

  weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', 'cityService', '$resource', function($scope, $resource, cityService){
          $scope.city = cityService.city;
     $scope.weatherApi = $resource('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast', {
     callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
     }, {get: { method: 'JSONP'}});


         $scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherApi.get({
         q: $scope.city, 
         cnt: 2,
        appid: 'b0a06997003bb34ff74635549a8bfd0e'
         });
     console.log($scope.weatherResult);
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [`https://openweathermap.org/current#name`](https://openweathermap.org/current#name), you should not pass a state name, just a city name and an optional country name. Therefore, [`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=XXX&q=New%20York,%20US`](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=b0a06997003bb34ff74635549a8bfd0e&q=New%20York,%20US) works, but [`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=XXX&q=New%20York,%20NY`](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=b0a06997003bb34ff74635549a8bfd0e&q=New%20York,%20NY) doesn't. Interestingly, [`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=XXX&q=New%20York,%20NY,%20US`](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=b0a06997003bb34ff74635549a8bfd0e&q=New%20York,%20NY,%20US) also works, although it doesn't look like it's documented.